# Can a valid HKEY be NULL?

Tags: qt, winapi

Can `RegOpenKeyEx`/`RegCreateKeyEx` return `NULL` as a valid `HKEY` value?

I'm analyzing the source code of `QSettings` (https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qsettings_win.cpp.html#_ZL15createOrOpenKeyiiRK7QStringi).

If `NULL` is a possible valid value for `HKEY`, then `QSettings`'s implementation under Windows has bug.

Comment: valid handle can not be 0. but implementation anyway is bad - need analyze status code returned but not `HKEY`. and return status code to caller

Comment: @RbMm "*need analyze status code returned but not HKEY*" - which is exactly what `QSettings` actually does, when it calls into the Registry API. "*and return status code to caller*" - not if the caller doesn't need the error code. The code in question returns a NULL hkey to the caller on failure. Which is perfectly fine, provided the caller checks the hkey for NULL before using it. Which this code does, AFAICS.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev "*`QSettings`'s implementation under Windows has bug*" - I'm not seeing a bug in the linked code related to misuse of a NULL hkey. Can you be more specific about what you think the bug is exactly?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau if *opened* `HKEY` can be NULL, then `QSettings` will treat it as a failure and will generate a error. There is no bug only in case *opened* `HKEY` can never be `NULL`. This is the whole question is about.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev "*if opened `HKEY` can be NULL*" - it can't. That is your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can `RegOpenKeyEx`/`RegCreateKeyEx` return NULL as a valid HKEY value?

No, a valid *opened* `HKEY` is never NULL.

On the other hand, the value of the returned `HKEY` is *indeterminate* if these functions fail.  The Win32 API documentation does not say one way or the other if the `HKEY` gets set to NULL on failure, so you can't rely *solely* on checking the returned `HKEY` for NULL vs non-NULL when calling these functions, eg:

```cpp
HKEY hKey; // uninitialized
RegOpenKeyEx(..., &hKey, ...);
if (hKey) {
    // use hKey as needed - undefined behavior!
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

The functions return 0 on success and non-zero on failure. The caller must look at that to determine whether the `HKEY` is valid or not, eg:

```cpp
HKEY hKey;
LONG res = RegOpenKeyEx(..., &hKey, ...);
if (res == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // use hKey as needed - OK!
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

And AFAICS, `QSettings` does exactly that, explicitly settings its `HKEY` variables to NULL when explicitly detecting failures, which is perfectly fine.

> If NULL is a possible valid value for HKEY

NULL is not a valid *opened* value for these functions to output, thus NULL is available for the application to set its `HKEY`s to when representing *unopened* keys.  Just like with most other Win32 handle/pointer types.

> then `QSettings`'s implementation under Windows has bug.

I'm not seeing any such bug in the code you linked to.  All uses of `RegOpeKeyEx()`/`RegCreateKeyEx()` are correct, they check the error code before using the returned `HKEY`, `HKEY` variables are being set to NULL for *unopened* keys, and no read/write operations are being performed on a NULL `HKEY`.  So where is the bug?

Comment: Any proof that opened `HKEY` is always non-NULL?

Comment: Again, I was asking if it's possible that RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS with HKEY set to NULL (and thus it's a valid opened key). If yes - QSettings has bug. If not - QSettings does not have bug. But it's not enough to just say Yes or No (you can be wrong). Some proof is required. Unfortunately I did not find anything related in MSDN.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev "*I was asking if it's possible that RegOpenKeyEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS with HKEY set to NULL*" - no, it is not possible. Which is covered in the very 1st sentence in my answer. "*it's not enough to just say Yes or No (you can be wrong)*" - I'm not wrong on this.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev "*Unfortunately I did not find anything related in MSDN*" - the only thing that is *documented* as saying a NULL `HKEY` is not a valid opened key is [`RegOverridePredefKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regoverridepredefkey), which uses NULL to indicate the LACK of an opened key to map to. But that should be enough to prove that `RegOpenKeyEx()`/`RegCreateKeyEx()` **cannot** return a NULL `HKEY` on success, otherwise `RegOverridePredefKey()` would not work properly, hence an *opened* key cannot be NULL.